Java SAXParser handling XML differently on AWS EC2 vs home (Windows) computer
I've been using Java's SAXParser successfully in production for years now, but an error has popped up in the last couple months:
Failed to parse url https://www.boardgamegeek.com/xmlapi2/thing?id=303215&stats=1
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: https://boardgamegeek.com/xmlapi2/thing?id=303215&stats=1; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.

Puzzling properties:

My XML parsing code has been running successfully for years on BoardGameGeek data (using their XML API2), and these errors only started appearing in October 2024. I checked my code's changelogs, and the relevant files (handler, parser, etc) haven't been touched since June 2024.
The parsing still works fine on the vast majority of game ids (95+%).
My other handlers for parsing other BGG data are still working 100% of the time; it is just the one for game data that (sometimes) fails.
The parser fails on different game ids depending on where I run it. For instance, the above url (with game id 303215) is parsed without issue if I run my code on my home computer (Windows). The above error only appears in production, running on either of my AWS EC2 instances (one using Amazon Linux 2023 and Corretto 21, the other using Amazon Linux 2 and Corretto 17).
I also have urls that work on my AWS EC2 instances but fail on my home computer, e.g. 413908.

Failed to parse url https://www.boardgamegeek.com/xmlapi2/thing?id=413908&stats=1
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: https://boardgamegeek.com/xmlapi2/thing?id=413908&stats=1; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.


The handler that fails is not particularly complex, and it doesn't even use StringBuilder / DefaultHandler's characters method (i.e. it is not an issue of failing to append to StringBuilder). The handler just checks qName and attributes.
Sometimes the problem just fixes itself (i.e. the same url gives the same error hundreds of times but then eventually gets parsed successfully). Though I suspect some change(s) to the page's content caused this.

FYI the error is always "Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.", both at home and in production.
Things I have checked trying to solve the issue:

Checking the url's xml using online validators.
Modifying my code to specify the encoding (rather than have it be detected automatically), and specifying different encodings.

try {
    InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(url);
    inputSource.setEncoding("UTF-8"); <-- I tried ISO-8859-1, Windows-1252, and UTF-16.
    parser.parse(inputSource, dh); <-- I used to just call parser.parse(url, dh);
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Failed to parse url " + url);
    System.out.println(e);
    if (e instanceof SAXException) { <-- Added this condition.
        System.out.println(e.getCause());
    }
}

I'm still looking into related topics (e.g. Byte Order Mark), but I'm not seeing anything that should work on Windows but not Linux or vice-versa (characters method would have been my first guess if I used it / overrode it in my handler, as happened here).
[Appended]
I don't think seeing my handler's code will be helpful, but here's some excerpts just in case:
@Override
public void startDocument() {
    primaryGameName = "";
    averageWeight = DBQueries.MAX_COMPLEXITY;
    yearPublished = -1;
    publisherMinAge = -1;
[...]
@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) {
    if ("name".equals(qName)) {
        if ("primary".equals(attributes.getValue("type"))) {
            if (attributeHasValue(attributes, "value")) {
                primaryGameName = attributes.getValue("value");
            } else {
                System.out.println("WARNING: game's name not found! " + attributes);
            }
        }
    } else if ("averageweight".equals(qName)) {
        if (attributeHasValue(attributes, "value")) {
            averageWeight = Float.parseFloat(attributes.getValue("value"));
        }
[...]
@Override
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) {
    if ("poll".equals(qName)) {
        isPollingPlayerCounts = false;
        isPollingPlayerAge = false;
[...]
private boolean attributeHasValue(Attributes attributes, String valueName) {
    return !(null == attributes.getValue(valueName) || attributes.getValue(valueName).isEmpty());
}


It sounds like the source is occasionally providing malformed data.  You say you've checked the XML against online validators, but are you sure you've checked examples identical to ones that your program rejected?  You say that at least sometimes, the problem clears on its own, so I don't think it's safe to assume that different downloads from the same URL will necessarily yield the same data.

Because if your program didn't change, then it seems most likely that the failures you observe are related to the data served by BGG changing.  At least on an intermitent basis.

@JohnBollinger That's true, but https://www.boardgamegeek.com/xmlapi2/thing?id=303215&stats=1 has been failing non-stop for the last 4 days (for AWS EC2 but not for Windows). So I think it's reasonable to assume the cause for failure is still there.

In it's responses to my queries, the BGG API is clear and consistent that UTF-8 is the intended encoding.  The HTTP response headers say so, and the XML declaration in the payload also says so (explicitly).  There should be no need to try different ones.  But as long as you are initializing your InputSource with a URI string, I'd consider not explicitly specifying an encoding at all.  The system should try to figure it out.  But it seems a long shot that that would resolve your particular issue.

@JohnBollinger Yes, the InputSource is something I tried adding to see if it would resolve the issue, but since it did not work I've removed it and am just calling parser.parse(url, dh); directly as before.

I think you should log the raw byte stream for examination, so that you can correlate the application errors with the actual input data.  If you don't otherwise have a way to do that then it shouldn't be too hard to write an InputStreamFilter that you can interpose to do that job.  I think you'll find that the byte stream is genuinely faulty in the failure cases.
